# Resource shared between static and non-static methods in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, static-methods, static

I know that `static` `synchronized` method locked on `class` object and while instance `synchronized` method locks on current instance of Object i.e. `this`.

Since both of these object are different they have different lock so while one thread is executing `static` `synchronized` method , other thread in java doesn’t need to wait for that thread to return instead it will acquire separate lock.

Consider following example

```
public class Test {
  static int count = 0;

  public synchronized void f1(){
    count++;
  }

  public static synchronized void f2(){
    count++;
  }
}
```

here shared count is not accessed in mutual exclusive fashion which may result in passing incorrect `count` to caller of `f1()` while another thread is incrementing `count` using `static` `f2()` method.

**What is solution over this situation? Am i am asking correct question if not please make me correct? And if it is a true situation then what solution does java pr ovoids?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use synchronized block on the non-static method and it should use the same monitor as the static synchronized method:

```
public void f1() {
   synchronized(Test.class) {
     count++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The rule of thumb is that static synchronized methods should be used to protect only static variables, while non-static synchronized methods should be used to protect only non-static variables.

Since `count` is static, modifying it from a block with non-static synchronization is incorrect. To code this correctly, and also to avoid code duplication, call `f2` from `f1`, like this:

```
public void f1(){
    ... // Do something ...
    f2();
    ... // Do something else ...
}

public static synchronized void f2(){
    count++;
}
```